# How to apply expiration message in dead letter queue (amq)

Tags: apache-camel, jms, activemq-classic

```
<policyEntry queue="Activemq.DLQ">
 <deadLetterStrategy>
 <sharedDeadLetterStrategy  processExpired="false" expiration="300000"/>
</deadLetterStrategy>
 </policyEntry>
```

above is my amq.xml changes. when i applied this changes, this broker unable to start easy to say is not running. My intentions is to put expiration towards all the messages in dlq and auto discard it. Any help is appreciated below is the error from amq log

```
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)[:1.7.0_45]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)[:1.7.0_45]
        at org.apache.activemq.console.Main.runTaskClass(Main.java:262)[activemq.jar:5.10.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.console.Main.main(Main.java:115)[activemq.jar:5.10.0]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)[:1.7.0_45]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)[:1.7.0_45]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)[:1.7.0_45]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)[:1.7.0_45]
        at org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp.run(WrapperSimpleApp.java:240)[wrapper.jar:3.2.3]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)[:1.7.0_45]
```

Comment: I can start ActiveMQ without any problems when I insert the above snippet into the default configuration. Are you sure this snippet causes the issues?

Comment: Hi burki, 
Thanks for your feedback here. Anyway  our TTL is set up to 0 for unlimited time means no expired for amq messaging but after certain time i can see a lot of meesage is automatically redirect to activemq.dlq so  from here http://activemq.apache.org/message-redelivery-and-dlq-handling.html i read on how to put the expiration and autodiscard all the message in dlq. But once i did this setup to this specific broker then im not able to start that broker. My concerns here is do we need to apply each individual dead letter strategy first ?

Thanks and any help is appreciated !

Comment: No I don't think you have to do any other thing first. I can take the XML from your question, insert it into my activemq.xml and my ActiveMQ starts without problems (version 5.13.x). What version do you use? If you post your complete activemq.xml I can give it a try on my installation. Perhaps you have another issue in your activemq.xml

Comment: Hi Burki, Thanks for your replied. Here am using 5.10 amq version. Most of the message in dlq mentioned about 'duplicate from store queue' do u know any other way to handle it ? am in-progress to update my amq xml but there is some restriction

Comment: "duplicate from store for queue"? Do you have multiple brokers? If not you could try to upgrade to activemq 5.11. See http://activemq.2283324.n4.nabble.com/dlqDeliveryFailureCause-java-lang-Throwable-duplicate-from-store-for-queue-td4691288.html

Comment: Hi Burki, Yes multiple brokers. So one of my brokers down after implemented above snippet. We are using tcp connectors for each brokers

Comment: You write you use ActiveMQ 5.10, but the attribute `expiration` is supported since version 5.12. Is this the reason your broker fails after inserting this XML snippet?

Comment: Hi burki, thanks for your above information provided. Now make sense why my broker isnt started after apply above snippet. Anyway i need to think the way to handle it on 5.10 version. Thanks again and this is the sentences from amq page  and before this i didnt notice this                                                                                                                        " By default, ActiveMQ will never expire messages sent to the DLQ. However, from ActiveMQ 5.12 the deadLetterStrategy supports an expiration attribute whose value is given in milliseconds."